# Button not working in Android application

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and trying to implement a simple button, which should display a message in a Toast (eventually it's going to be used to create an account). But nothing happens when I press the button, no errors are displayed on the logcat either so I must be missing something obvious but I can't find it!!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.laptop.whatsfordinner" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--Splash Screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <!--Register User -->
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="Register User">
    </activity>
</application>

<!--  Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

**registration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_title1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <!-- Input Name -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.08"></LinearLayout>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Username Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_title2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <!-- Input Username -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Email Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_title3"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <!-- Input Email -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_title4"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <!-- Input Password -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Button Register-->

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="@string/reg_button1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**RegistrationActivity.java**

```
 package com.example.laptop.whatsfordinner;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity {


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

        // Create button
       Button btnRegister1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        // button click event
        btnRegister1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new account in background thread
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Example action.",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

**Registration.java**

```
package com.example.laptop.whatsfordinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class Registration extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static Registration newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Registration fragment = new Registration();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public Registration() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainPage) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is this enabled attribute in button xml?

Comment: the code seems fine.

Comment: enabled means that the button is available to user input, but from the code everything seems fine

Comment: Is it `registration.xml` or `Registration.xml` (your file name)? Not that it should make a difference, unless for some reason you have both registration.xml and Registration.xml files, as it would throw an error if you tried to access a layout that didn't exist in your resources. You could try removing the clickable and enabled attributes (not that it should make a difference it is just redundant code)

Comment: not related to the Toast displaying, but your application doesn't have a launcher activity. How is it even starting ?

Comment: sorry my mistake, it is supposed to be registration.xml

Comment: how      registration.xml      appears with a error naming ?

Comment: @LinX64 The app runs fine, I took some bits out the Manifest file to prevent the page going on for ages. Even when I am clicking the button, it does not bring up anything on the logcat

Comment: your manifest says the launcher activity is .Mainpage...how can you see Registration.Java then?

Comment: He starts RegistrationActivity from Main activity, that's not he's problem, he sees the button and clicks on it

Comment: I suggesting using `Log.d()` and/or `System.out.println()` to add messages to your logcat to help you figure out what is going on. Everything looks fine with your code as far as I can see.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice :- Tried your solution but no success.

Comment: @LinX64 I'm not sure what you mean by "the Activity couldn't run without AppCompat". Are you referring to the appcompat support library? If done correctly, you can certainly create an app that never uses this library.

Comment: @AdarshYadav What do you mean "no success"? Where did you add debugging messages to your code? What did you see in your logcat?

Comment: Adding `Log.d()` messages isn't a one-time, all-or-nothing deal. You need to keep adding output to strategic places in your code until you figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - yeah, you're right, i didn't think about it, but, it sounds unusual.

Comment: @LinX64 It is unusual only because an app of any amount of sophistication will need classes from the support libraries.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - Exactly, (i was just trying to see if there was any error, btw) so what do you think? the question is not clear and sometimes flagging it will fix everything i guess, am i wrong? the OP doesn't know anything about debugging, which means, he/she should be a beginner.mentioned also: **I am new to Android**

Comment: @LinX64 Flagging what? The question? How will that fix anything? Also, since the OP doesn't know how to debug, I feel it is best to offer suggestions to help him learn how.

Comment: If you properly indent the Manifest XML, you'll see a clear problem that it is misconfigured...

Comment: Please show us the actual `AndroidManifest.xml` file that you have. As @cricket_007 says, the one in your question is full of problems which means it isn't the same as the one that you used to successfully run your app. We cannot help you unless we have code which exactly recreates the issue you encountered.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - yeah well, everyone is trying to help him/her, no problem, but what about the OP try? by the way, what a question...:)

Comment: @Theman - Please put your exactly codes without missing something, that worked (except the `Manifest` problem) by the way.(even if it is possible, your imports too).

Comment: I have updated the code to how I have it in Android Studio. There's commented out code which shouldn't affect it so I didn't include that

Comment: @Theman - that worked for me, not sure what are you exactly missing.

Comment: I created another button on another page and tried doing the same thing but it doesn't work, even something simple like using System.out.println() It works for my navigation menu but not the widget buttons for some reason.

Comment: @LinX64 Maybe my project is corrupted or something is wrong with the Button class. I created a new project, created a button and made it print to the terminal and it worked...

Comment: Yes, if it is not a problem, you can send that old project i really enjoy that if i can find the solution :)

Comment: @LinX64 can you check the Registration.java file please? I edited the question to include it. Please let me know if there is anything conflicting methods that might mess things up!

Comment: You never set a button click listener in your Fragment! But where do you use that Fragment is the new question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inflating a `Layout` in a `Fragment` and in an `Activity`.

If you want to handle that `Button` in your `Fragment`, do this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        Button regButton1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        regButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

The code in your `Activity` looks good but, you were inflating the same `Layout` for both.

**See:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.registration);
```

**And:**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration, container, false);
```

Also, Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to remove the unused import, finally, it should be like this(Your `Fragment`'s imports):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

And like i guessed, the problem is because you were inflating a `Layout` in a `Fragment` and in an `Activity`.and i've tried that and it worked with that `Activity`.

(nice question by the way).

---

**Solution:**
Set your own `Layout` for `Fragment` and your `Activity` but not the same `Layout` for both.

Then, you're ready to go.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, the Fragment isn't used in any activity, though

Comment: Yes exactly, but the most interesting part was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207636/button-not-working-in-android-application?noredirect=1#comment58142292_35207636 and that was the another issue/problem.

Comment: Haha, what? Anyways **hopefully** this addresses the problem

Comment: I hope so :) perhaps there was other problems which causes that issue